# Wolfram Mathematica after upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var

Tags: upgrade, fonts, shared-library, 19.04, mathematica

I have recently upgraded my desktop PC from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04. Now I am getting the following error when I try to start ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶g̶r̶a̶m̶s̶ Wolfram Mathematica 11.3:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
```

I tried to check this command:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffbd1e9000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f723c2e6000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f723c2a9000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f723c2a0000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f723c27f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f723c094000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f723c05d000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f723c03f000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f723c401000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f723bef1000)
```

But I am not that advanced linux user to understand what all these things mean.

Has anyone seen this problem?

Comment: What exactly is *"one of my programs"*? is it a program provided by the Ubuntu repositories - or a 3rd party application that you installed from elsewhere?

Comment: It's Wolfram Mathematica. Although I don't think it is the problem in the particular program. It was working fine but stopped after the upgrade.

Comment: It looks like it is very much a problem with the particular program - see for example [Can't launch Mathematica 11 on Fedora 29](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189306/cant-launch-mathematica-11-on-fedora-29)

Comment: Yep, this helped indeed! I will correct the question and post an answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As noticed by @steeldriver, the problem is specific to Wolfram Mathematica. I **solved the issue** by following some of the steps from this question: [Can't launch Mathematica 11 on Fedora 29](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189306/cant-launch-mathematica-11-on-fedora-29). For the record, I write down here what I did.

Go to `MathematicaInstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/` (for me it is `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64`) and run the following commands:

```
sudo mv libfreetype.so.6 libfreetype.so.6.bak
sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.bak
```

Just to test, I tried to start Mathematica right after renaming the first file, `libfreetype.so.6`. It did not work and I got the following error:

```
$ mathematica 
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Binaries/Linux-x86-64/Mathematica: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)
```

But after renaming the second file, everything works fine.

**NB**. The link provided above has more information on other potentially helpful steps.

Comment: Thanks now mathematica start, but adding a subchapter leads to an error/wrong formating. ;-(

Comment: Sorry, which subchapter?..

Comment: I hit the same problem with Mathematica 10.0.2 on Linux Mint 20 (Ubuntu 20.04-based) and this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I also updated my Ubuntu from 18.10 to 19.04 and got the same issue.
I managed to repair that thanks to some reading (among which @Yauhen's). Here are the command lines I used:

```
cd /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/
sudo mv libfreetype.so.6 libfreetype.so.6.bak
sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.bak

cd
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

et voilà :)

Comment: I have also updated from 18.04 to 19.04 and then Mathematica was not starting. You trick worked like magic! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation :)

Comment: Thanks now mathematica start, but adding a subchapter leads to an error/wrong formating. ;-(

Comment: Worked a treat !

Answer (score 1):

On 5.13.13-arch1-1 (updated September 1 2021) I had same problem.

After searching and not finding a solution, I copied the previous versions of `libz` and `libfreetype` from a working installation of Mathematica and  pasted them into `Mathematica-FOLDER/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64`.

Now Mathematica works again.

I have provided the two libraries on this [Google drive share](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z0ExZtxmAJ4AXOUEm085tLdL141dladn?usp=sharing).

Answers:

> Are the two libraries on the Google drive from your previous versions
> of libz and libfreetype?

The files are libfreetype.so.6.14.4 and libz.so.1.2.11 I extracted from /usr/lib64/

> Somehow I don't feel comfortable loading binary files from someone's
> Google Drive... O.o

Of course, you could extract of a previous version of archlinux or search on web for these libraries.

> What would be more useful is the version compatibility match to be
> listed. What were/are the versions of the libz and libfreetype, and
> what is the version of Mathematica, with which they are compatible.
> Also, what were the versions fo the libraries that were incompatible?
> Please edit your answer and add that information, if you can. Thanks.

libfreetype.so.6.14.4 and libz.so.1.2.11   Thank you I hope these answers help to solve problems.

Comment: Are the two libraries on the Google drive from your previous versions of libz and libfreetype?

Comment: Somehow I don't feel comfortable loading binary files from someone's Google Drive... O.o

Comment: What would be more useful is the version compatibility match to be listed. What were/are the versions of the `libz` and `libfreetype`, and what is the version of Mathematica, with which they are compatible. Also, what were the versions fo the libraries that were incompatible? Please [edit] your answer and add that information, if you can. Thanks.